# How can i convert this sql query to entity framework

Tags: sql, entity-framework

```
WITH addColumn AS (    select rank() OVER (ORDER BY  [m-pay_sub_ops_date] ) as rank, *
   From [m-pay_subscriber_operations]
    ),

 partitioned AS (
  SELECT
    *,
   rank - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by rank) AS grp
  FROM addColumn
  WHERE  [m-pay_sub_ops_result_code] = '73' and [m-pay_sub_ops_msisdn_pioneer] = '22103248'
),
counted AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY  grp) AS cnt
  FROM partitioned
),
ranked AS (SELECT

*,
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [m-pay_sub_ops_date] desc, grp) AS rnk
FROM counted where cnt >5 

)
SELECT
  [m-pay_sub_ops_date] , [m-pay_sub_ops_msisdn_pioneer], [m-pay_sub_ops_result_code], grp, cnt
FROM ranked
WHERE rnk = 1
;
```

Comment: This query is much too complex to be expressed as LINQ expressions. Your best bet is to use it as a stored procedure.

Comment: We long ago stopped trying to convert all of our SQL Queries to Entity Framework. Something like this I wouldn't event try. We use EF for Adds, Updates, Deletes, and Simple Selects. In ref to Presser's statement, using a Stored Procedure isn't necessary, but would work just fine.

Comment: Return back to initial task, forget Sql and probably it's just single while/iterator over source  will do in c#/vb/ code. Share initial task if you can.